# Adobe Reader DC - Navigation Panes: Default Width

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, pdf-reader, sidebar, adobe-reader-dc

### How can I set the default width of the Navigation Bars in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

I am getting this every time I open a new document or collapse and extend again the Navigation Bars:

[image]

How could I extend their width as to keep them fixed like this for every PDF document, whenever I open the Navigation Bars?

[image]